# How do I store CSV format data in sqlite databases

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite

I have a CSV file for backup and I want to append my data back in sqlite database from CSV file.
How do I store the data back into the databases of react native app

CSV format is :

```
'a', 'b', 'c'
'A1', B1, C1
'A2', B2, C2
'A3', B3, C3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finished after using a package called [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse)